# Add one more UITableViewRowAction when cell already shows two

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I'll talk about UITableViewRowAction which is availeble from iOS 8. I need to made 2 things

1. When user swipes left show 2 UITableViewRowActions (delete and favorite)
   This one Im already made buy adding 2 UITableViewRowActions in

   - tableView: editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:

[image: Here how it looks]

2. When the user taps to "delete" row action which is already shows - I need to show one more row action (confirmation)

[image: Here what i need after trash pressed]

I have no mind how to add row action from row action handler...
Sorry for bad English.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is impossible. Adding a row action dynamically requires reloading the tableview, and this would require the user to swipe to the left again. You then would need to set a property (waitingForConfirmation = true), and then add the rowAction in editActionsForRowAtIndexPath if the property is set to true. This will not be user friendly at all, and I do not view it as a valid solution.

The best solution would probably be to show a UIAlertController and then ask the user to confirm, and run the required code afterwards by adding the code in the completion handler of the button.